# I need to learn how to work with ROS in 2 months, what is the recommended book or website in addition to ROS Tutorials?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a beginner.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263591/i-need-to-learn-how-to-work-with-ros-in-2-months,-what-is-the-recommended-book-or-website-in-addition-to-ros-tutorials?/) by [MohammedHyder](https://answers.ros.org/users/30707/mohammedhyder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can start here: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials

And this book is pretty explanatory: http://mastering-ros.com/

There are several video tutorials on YouTube

---

Originally posted by [orko](https://answers.ros.org/users/30575/orko/) with karma: 91 on 2017-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MohammedHyder](https://answers.ros.org/users/30707/mohammedhyder/) on 2017-06-29**:
Thank you very much!